# According to Hindu Mythology, why do people produce smoke, light and ring the bell?

Tags: myth-identification, hindu

Could you please explain, while doing worshiping, according to Hindu Mythology, why do people produce smoke through burning joss sticks; light a candle-like light called "Dip jyoti" prepared from cotton-swab and mustard oil or margarine; and ring a metallic bell (made up of alloy of brass and iron) and while doing so all the three items (joss sticks, light, and bell are moved around the "Almighty" in clock-wise direction?

Answer (score 3):

In [Aarti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aarti), a part of the [Puja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puja_(Hinduism)) ritual, the burning of incense is said to be cleaning the air, and thus making it easier for the [devas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deva_(Hinduism)) or other divine beings to manifest themselves in the place of incantation. This ritual is not limited to worship, but is also used to welcome a guest to your house (making it easier for him/her to reside in your house by purifying the air). In Indian movies you can often see a guest being welcomed in this way, the host can wave the incense over the head of the guest using their hands.

As for the candle-lighting, this [video for children](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXG2m7bwXJ4&ab_channel=ShemarooBhakti) has some English translations of an accompanying incantation text that explain its purpose.

The ringing of the bell (a clear sound) welcomes the deities in a similar philosophy as the incense.